# Hiding Applet Viewer which was started by Java Web Start

Tags: java, applet, jframe, java-web-start, jnlp

I have an applet which is opening by Java Web Start.
Java Web Start uses applet viewer to display my applet.
As soon as applet loads it opens a JFrame.
And user interracts with the JFrame. Applet on the appletViewer becames useless.
I want to hide the applet viewer window.

> When I set widht=0 height=0 on the jnlp file.

Java Web Starts gives error and does not open the application.
(something like widht cannot be zero.)

I tried to call the belov methods on the applet but. 
It does not seem to have any effect.

```
setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
setVisible(false);
```

**how can i hide the applet viewer window?**

[image]

Comment: Forget the applet.  Open the frame directly using Java Web Start.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I said applet window is useless but it is only in this case. Applet works differently on different customers therefor i have to keep the applet.

Comment: You seem to have completely missed my point.  Let me ask you this.  What does the applet do, ***besides*** opening the frame?

Comment: @AndrewThompson   Applet is hosted more than over 50 web servers. 
In some servers it does not open the frame and shows the gui in itself directly.
In Some servers it opens a frame and shot the gui in it.
handles proxies defined on ie.
gets parameters,gets images,
opens browser frames,calls java scripts. etc..
Applet is very old and has a very bad code.
(espicially incredible amount of applet parameters)
Yes i can change the code and open it as an application 
but it is not practical to me right now. it will be my last choice.

Comment: windowListener.windowClosing(new WindowEvent(w,0));
sending window event to the window of the applet 
closes the applet viewer (while myframe does not close)
But i dont feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Old thread... but could you add the full resolution, I'm struggling with this issue as well at the moment, old enterprise applet that is reaching end of life and we're trying to save it for a few more months with JavaWebStart...)